# Django Resf Framework: auto fill a field of a Model when POST?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, relational-database, autofill

Is there a way of filling some particular fields in a model using a field value of another model object?

For example, I thought of the following scenario:
**1 - there are some models**

```
from django.db import models

class Supplier(models.Model):
    supplier = models.Charfield(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Object(models.Model):
    object = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field="supplier")

class Transaction(models.Model):
    object_id = models.ForeignKey(Object, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    supplier = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
```

**2 - Those models are serialized**

```
from . import models
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

class SupplierSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Supplier
        fields = '__all__'

class ObjectSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Object
        fields = '__all__'

class TransactionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Transaction
        exclude = ('supplier',)
```

**3 - And there is a view**

```
from . import models, serializers
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

class TransactionApiViewset(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Transaction.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TransactionSerializer
```

When submiting a post with 'object_id' field to Transaction Api, I'd like that the 'supplier' field in Transaction Model autofills with the 'supplier' field value of Object object related to 'object_id'.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use property(or cached_property) method for `supplier` instead of saving as a field:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    object = models.ForeignKey(Object, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def supplier(self):
        return self.object.supplier.supplier
```

If you need to keep `supplier` saved in `Transaction` table, then just keep the model definition as you posted, and add a `validate` method in serializer:

```
class TransactionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    def validate(self, data):
        object = Object.objects.get(id=data["object_id"])
        data["supplier"] = object.supplier.supplier
        return data
```

That would automatically update `Transaction` with new object related supplier's `supplier` field.

Comment: This property method could be used to fill some field? Cause I need that field in the Transaction Table.

Comment: @marcosnolasco sure, the answer was updated per your comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my problem! I'd upvote your answer if i had enough 'reputation' ^^